# Are there any plugins to handle frames and framesets for Selenium IDE?

Tags: java, javascript, plugins, selenium, frames

From what I have experienced:

*The selenium IDE does not record frame or window changes.*

But it should.  And I think it's feasible.

I want to write a plugin, but first I want to make sure that such a plugin doesn't already exist.

Also, is there a place where all available plugins are stored?  And is there an easy tutorial on creating a plugin with good explanations?